# Getting unwanted URL in the xml Tags in the out put. BPEL Oracle SOA 11g

Tags: xml, soa, jdeveloper, bpel, oracle-soa

In my BPEL i have caught a fault in a catch block. Within the catch block i have a assign activity which will map the input payload(data) to the fault variable and populate a jms queue. From that jms queue one more service picks up the data and sends an error mail.
Now in the error mail i am getting the payload as:

```
<sal:salesUser xmlns:sal="http://www.mycompany.com/schemas/SalesUserMessage"> <!--Optional: -->
<sal1:userID xmlns:sal1="http://www.mycompany.com/schemas/SalesUserObject">123ABC</sal1:userID>
</sal:salesUser>
```

But if i check the flow trace the payload was looking something like this and i believe should be getting the below data without URls in my mail:

```
<sal:syncSalesUser>
<!-- Optional:
                 -->
<sal1:userID>123ABC</sal1:userID>
<!-- Optional:
                 -->
</sal:syncSalesUser>
```

Please tell me why i am getting the url within the xml tags in the mail.

PFB the assign section of my catch black:

```
<catch faultName="bpelx:remoteFault" faultVariable="RuntimeFaultVar">
  <sequence name="seq_RemoteFault">
    <assign name="assign_RemotefaultMessage">
      <copy>
        <from expression="oraext:get-content-as-string(bpws:getVariableData('receiveInput_InVar','userNotify','/ns22:userNotify/ns22:payload/ns22:user'))"/>
        <to variable="FaultMessage" part="payload"
            query="/ns7:FaultSchema/ns7:FaultMessage/ns7:Payload"/>
      </copy>
    </assign>
    <invoke name="publish_RemoteFaultToQueue"
            partnerLink="publish_ErrorToQueue"
            portType="ns3:Produce_Message_ptt" operation="Produce_Message"
            inputVariable="invoke_jms_publish_ErrorToQueue"/>
    <terminate name="Terminate"/>
  </sequence>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the flowtrace the namespace url(xmlns:sal="http://www.mycompany.com/schemas/SalesUserMessage") are displayed on the top. That's why you don't see them. If you don't want to see those, you have to modify your variable to remove the namespaces as described here http://orasoa.blogspot.fr/2008/12/remove-namespaces-in-osb-and-bpelesb.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want your desired output you should consider using a xquery to get rid of all namespaces.

Try the xquery below:

```
xquery version "1.0" encoding "Cp1252";
(:: pragma  parameter="$anyType1" type="xs:anyType" ::)
(:: pragma  type="xs:anyType" ::)

module namespace xf="http://tempuri.org/Cancel_Order/RemoveNamespace";

declare function xf:strip-namespace($e as element())as element()
{element { fn:QName("",fn:local-name($e)) }
{ for $child in $e/(@*,node())
 return  
 if ($child instance of element())
    then xf:strip-namespace($child)
       else $child
       }
 };
```

Hope it helps